# Cakephp 3 updating to PHP7 gives an intl extension error

Tags: cakephp-3.0, php-7, intl

I updated my server to PHP7, now CakePHP gives this error:

```
Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/ID/config/bootstrap.php on line 38
```

I installed `apt-get install -y php7.0-intl`

Reading all over the internet, I updated /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini to

```
[intl]
;intl.default_locale =
; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error
; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.
; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.
intl.error_level = 0
intl.use_exceptions = 0
```

I made sure it is loaded in ini

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
```

But it is still not working.

Comment: did you try php -m?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making these changes?

Comment: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini, is the output of php -m. And I even rebooted.

Comment: Is that for sure the ini file that is being used by PHP under Apache? Just noticed that it has "cli" in the path, which could indicate that PHP on the command line is using a different ini file than PHP in the web server is.

Comment: Indeed, that's what was wrong. Thank you for spotting this!

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini file uncomment the following line;

```
;extension=php_intl.dll;
```

and make it to:

```
extension=php_intl.dll;
```

Comment: I'm on Debian, this dll is only for Windows no?

Comment: are you using any xampp or something else ?

Comment: No, it's a VPS.

Comment: No matter but do you have php.ini file ?

Comment: if not use the following link and do what i have suggested in answer above..http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/server-usage/edit-main-phpini

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal:

```
   sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```